Oracle APEX how to globalize header values of Web Service
In an Oracle APEX application, I have several pages that use the same web service call, which I created in Shared Components > Web Services References. The problem is that I need to manually specify the HTTP request headers (Accept, Authorization, and Content-Type) on every page, every time. For instance, when the token used for the Authorization header expired, I had to update it manually across all the pages. Is there a way to centralize or globalize the header values so that I can set them in one place only?
Here is how my web service looks like:


This seems more a conventional JavaScript issue than a GIS-centric one, more suitable to [so].
